# Transaction error handling not working Neo4jphp

Tags: transactions, cypher, neo4jphp, neo4j

I tried to use `$transaction->isError()` and `$transaction->isClosed` in neo4j transaction, but these functions failed to catch the error.

Below is my code, where I did the transaction roll-back after committing, which according to the documentation should produce an error and it should be handled by `isClosed()`, but it never handled the error rather produced the error.

### code

```
require("vendor/autoload.php");
        use Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query;
        $client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client();

        $transaction = $client->beginTransaction();

        $queryA = new Query($client, 'CREATE (n:testing{id:189})');
        $result = $transaction->addStatements($queryA);
        $transaction->commit();
        $transaction->rollback(); // performing rollback after commit
if ($transaction->isClosed()) {
    echo "No more statements can be added!";
}
```

### Error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Everyman\Neo4j\Exception' with message 'Transaction is already closed' in C:\xampp\htdocs\feed\vendor\everyman\neo4jphp\lib\Everyman\Neo4j\Transaction.php on line 149
```

But actually this error should be handled by `$transaction->isClosed()`,but it didin't

Please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't rollback after a commit. The commit closes the transaction, so attempting to rollback throws an error.

You don't need to `rollback` after the `commit`. Rolling back will automatically happen on the server if any of the added statements fails. You only need to call `rollback` if your application manually needs to rollback the transaction, which you should do before committing.

Comment: How would I know the transaction has an error and it is rollbacked?
Also how should I manually rollback? 
if i have mutiple databases in same application, so i have to rollback entire transaction in Neo4j and other databases if any one of them fails. So in terms of neo4j how would i know failed transaction in a conditional statement.

Comment: The statement that fails will throw and exception. Also, you can see if a given transaction has an error by calling `$transaction->isError()`. If you have multiple databases, you should check each connection separately for errors, and only rollback the ones that haven't failed. The one that has failed will already have been rolled back on the server. Relevant docs here: https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Cypher-Transactions#wiki-managing-a-transaction

Comment: when neo4j is crashed, the neo4j will automatically rollback, but it wont be handled by $transaction->isError() , so that I cannot rollback my other database because $transaction->isError() return false

Comment: Then wrap the rollback call in a try-catch block. But I would be much more concerned about why the database is crashing. Fix that first.